# Trigger Animation on an element using only pure CSS with its keyframe Assigned

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I want some animation to be triggered to onclick of an element only using pure css. I have already assigned keyframe to this *class container*. There is a *tag* So when I click this, *container's* animation get started. Is it possible without using jquery ? In simple words when button is clicked animations get started with the assigned keyframe.

HTML

```
<div class="container container-anim">
   <div class="psw align-self-center">
       <a style="color:maroon" href="#reset">Back to log-in page</a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-anim {    
animation-name: stretch;    
animation-duration: 1.5s; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes stretch {
0% {transform: scale(1);}
50%{ }
100%{transform: scale(1.2);}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I know off to trigger animation without using some sort of JS to attach the class to the div element.

I would just use an onclick and jquery (or vanilla js)

```
<div class="container" onclick="$('.container').addClass('container-anim');">
   <div class="psw align-self-center">
       <a style="color:maroon" href="#reset">Back to log-in page</a> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but there's a restriction as mentioned in the question already

Answer (score 0):

An approach you can try is using the [`:active` pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#dynamic-pseudo-classes), this plays your animation when you click on any element.
as so:

```css
.container-anim:active {    
animation-name: stretch;    
animation-duration: 1.5s; 
animation-iteration-count: infinite;

}

@keyframes stretch {
0% {transform: scale(1);}
50%{ }
100%{transform: scale(1.2);}
}
```

```html
<div class="container container-anim">
   <div class="psw align-self-center">
       <a class="a" style="color:maroon" href="#reset">Back to log-in page</a> 
   </div>
   </div>
```